# Overflow is always disabled in react component, and it works only on the body tag

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I want my page to have a similar look to facebook's messenger, in which the messaging component and the sidebar have separate scrollbars, but the problem is, the overflow only works on the body tag, like.. i can scroll all the page at the same time, and if I overflow each component separately, the overflow is disabled.
this is the component in which I want to overflow.

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./css/content.css";
import Items from "./items";


const Content = () => {
  return (
    <div className="inner-content">
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Items />
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
};
```

css:

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll; /* works */
}
.inner-content {
  overflow-y: scroll; /* is disabled.... */
}
.items {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.item{
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  min-width: 280px;
  max-width: 280px;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your final HTML looks like since you only provide a part of it, but this snippet should get you going. It leaves the main page scrollable and adds a small, fixed position window in the front, just like Facebook's messenger.

```css
.messenger {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 10vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
  overflow: scroll;
}


.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="items">
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
</div>
<div class="messenger">
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
<div class="item">asd</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: found out that I forgot to add a height to it :)), thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import './styles/shopping.css'

export default props => (
  <div className='container-fluid' style={{ backgroundColor: '#3c096c', paddingTop: 10 }}>
    <div className='row d-flex justify-content-around p-2'>
      <div className='cardCss col-9 col-sm-5 col-lg-2'>
        <p>Teste</p>
        <p>Teste</p>
        <p>Teste</p>
        <p>Teste</p>
        <p>Teste</p>
      </div>
      <div className='cardCss col-9 col-sm-5 col-lg-2'>
        <p>Teste</p>
      </div>
      <div className='cardCss col-9 col-sm-5 col-lg-2'>
        <p>Teste</p>
      </div>
      <div className='cardCss col-9 col-sm-5 col-lg-2'>
        <p>Teste</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

My code css

```
.chamaCss {
    background-color: white;
}

.cardCss {
    background-color: white;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

In this example, only my div with classname = cardCSS has scrolling.

That is, a separate scroll